# Prove that if there are $(m-1)n+1$ persons in a room then there are $m$ mutual strangers (in the room) or there is a person quainted with $n$ persons.

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that if there are $(m-1)n+1$ persons in a room then there are $m$ mutual strangers (in the room) or there is a person quainted with $n$ persons.
The solution given in the book is as follows:

> We must proof that there are $m$ mutual strangers in the room or there are $n+1$ mutual acquaintances. We will repeat the following step:Select any person left in the room and remove his strangers . This is repeated $n$ times . At each step at most $m-1$ persons are removed . There will be at least $1$ person left.The persons selected and any of the persons left are $n+1$ mutual acquaintances.
>
> > However, I am not getting the part where it says to select any person and remove his strangers and it says that there are at most $m-1$ strangers. How do they make such a conclusion? Why do the no. of strangers for a person cannot be more than $m-1$? Furthermore, how are they certain that they can repeat this process for $n$ times? I mean if there are at most $m-1$ strangers then , maybe we can repeat this process $n$ times but how can we prove it so? Finally, how does they make the final conclusion that the persons selected and any of the persons left are $n+1$ mutual aqaintances.

Comment: Although this solution is wrong, the idea can be taken to solve this problem with essentially no change. Suppose there no people know at least $n$ people. Then, every time for a people we take out $n-1$ people it knows, and we take $m-1$ times. After that, there are $m$ people remaining so these $m$ people are mutual strangers. The previous argument is a solution close to what your book writes, but not the same.

Comment: @JetfiRex Can you please explain the fact that when we are assuming that no person knows at least $n$ people then how can we say for sure that they know $n-1$ people...i mean he can know $n-2$ persons as well or say,$n-3$ persons ....

Comment: Oh, that is a point... but the point of the proof is, every time we take out all the person it knows, so it is at most $n-1$ people. If there are less than $n-1$ people, it is even better. We can pick some random people to make it $n-1$ people picked out, the proof will not change.

Comment: It is like, First, we pick a person $A$, and then, after we take out $n-1$ people, the rest of the people $A$ does not know any of them. Then, take the second people $B$, and also take out the $n-1$ people, so the rest of the people $B$ does not know (and so does $A$). After we take $m-1$ times, we picked $m-1$ people, and taken out $(n-1)(m-1)$ people. These $m-1$ people don't know each other, and there is $(m-1)n+1-n(m-1)=1$ people left, these $m-1$ people does not know the only people left. So those $m$ people don't know each other.

Comment: @JetfiRex Thanks a lot! But can you please explain why we are  repeating the process $m-1$ times ...for eg if we repeat the process $m$ times we have $m-n+1$ persons left...similarly we can repeat this process more than $m$ times as well and less than $m-1$ times as well....

Comment: Why $m-1$ times: because we can NOT do more than $m-1$ times. Remember, we only have ONE, not $m$ people left! we PICKED $m-1$ people and thrown away $(m-1)(n-1)$ people, so that is why we only have one person left. Of course we CAN do less than $m-1$ times, but this is not sufficient to finish the proof. We need $m$ people there so we need to proceed $m-1$ times.

Comment: @JetfiRex Yeah,Thank you! I get it now...